# Unable to copy PDF generated by Latex

Tags: xetex, pdf

So this is rather strange. I generated a PDF file using Xelatex engine. It looks just the same as every other PDF file. But when I tried to copy the text from that PDF file, I'm unable to copy. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or regular right click doesn't make a difference at all.
[image]
**Edit:** the viewer doesn't make a difference. I have tried with both the Preview default and the adobe acrobat.

Comment: Which pdf viewer do you employ?

Comment: see the edit above

Comment: Do other documents typeset with xelatex show the same behavior? What TeX Distribution are you using? I just typeset a document with xelatex in teXShop and had no problem copying from its pdf preview which uses the same framework as Preview. Given that the document has a Confidential watermark could it be Locked from copying?

Comment: Yes. This is a recurring problem.  apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % latex -v
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)  I am not the one that add a confidential watermark. May I ask how do I check if it is locked form copying?